# Parsing structured file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to parse a large log file (about 500mb). If this isnt the right tool for the job please let me know.

I have a log file with its contents structured like this. Each section can have extra key value pairs:

```
requestID: saldksadk
time: 92389389
action: foobarr
----------------------
requestID: 2393029
time: 92389389
action: helloworld
source: email
----------------------
requestID: skjflkjasf3
time: 92389389
userAgent: mobile browser
----------------------
requestID: gdfgfdsdf
time: 92389389
action: randoms
```

I was wondering if there is an easy way to handle each section's data in the log. A section can span multiple lines, so I can't just split the string. For example, is there an easy way to do something like this:

```
for(section in log){
   // handle section contents
}
```

Comment: Don't downvote if you are not going to give a specific reason. Upvoting

Comment: First thing, don't try to load 500MB into memory at once, which is what you'd have to do to `split` the file. It's just not a scalable solution.

Comment: I never said I wanted to load it all into memory...  That is why I posted here to look for advice.

Comment: Nice edit... What would suggest then?

Comment: Are the hyphened lines always the same length?

Comment: Many of these solutions could be extended to stream data rather than collect it in memory all at once using `yield`, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using icktoofay's idea, and by using a [custom record separator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-each_line), I got this:

```
require 'yaml'

File.open("path/to/file") do |f|
  f.each_line("\n----------------------\n") do |line|
    puts YAML::load(line.sub(/\-{3,}/, "---")).inspect
  end
end
```

The output:

```
{"requestID"=>"saldksadk", "time"=>92389389, "action"=>"foobarr"}
{"requestID"=>2393029, "time"=>92389389, "action"=>"helloworld", "source"=>"email"}
{"requestID"=>"skjflkjasf3", "time"=>92389389, "userAgent"=>"mobile browser"}
{"requestID"=>"gdfgfdsdf", "time"=>92389389, "action"=>"randoms"}
```

Comment: Instead of `f = File.new "path/to/file"
f.each_line("----------------------") ...` use `File.foreach('path/to/file', "----------------------") ...`. Ruby will automatically close the file after the block exits.

Comment: I think the argument to `each_line` should have a newline at the beginning and end; otherwise, it will split on dashes in the middle of the line.

Comment: @icktoofay It won't if the hyphens are always the same number. If they were variable lengths though, you'd need to do a bit more work on the inside to clear up records of only hyphens, but that's not so bad, perhaps `next if line.start_with? "-"` or something like that.

Comment: @iain: I was referring to dashes inside of values, like `userAgent: Mozilla----------------------Firefox`

Comment: @icktoofay Ah, I see. I tested it and it still works, so I've updated the answer with that.

Answer (score 4):

That looks *like* [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/), although it is not exactly YAML. (YAML separates documents with exactly three dashes, no more.) You might try to mangle your document somehow such that lines consisting of only hyphens are collapsed into three hyphens so it is valid YAML. After that, you can feed it into a YAML parser.

Comment: is ---------------------- valid in yaml?

Comment: @lc2817: Yup; it separates documents. See [the spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395).

Comment: @lc2817: Actually, pardon me; it appears that three and only three dashes are allowed. I had incorrectly assumed that more than three dashes were allowed. You are right; it is incorrect YAML.

Comment: @icktoofay Good idea, +1. I've used this for idea for my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I saved your sample text to a file called "test.txt". Opening it with:

```
File.foreach('test.txt').slice_before(/^---/).to_a
```

returns:

```
[
  ["requestID: saldksadk\n", "time: 92389389\n", "action: foobarr\n"], 
  ["----------------------\n", "requestID: 2393029\n", "time: 92389389\n", "action: helloworld\n", "source: email\n"], 
  ["----------------------\n", "requestID: skjflkjasf3\n", "time: 92389389\n", "userAgent: mobile browser\n"], 
  ["----------------------\n", "requestID: gdfgfdsdf\n", "time: 92389389\n", "action: randoms\n"]
]
```

By running each sub-array through a filter we can strip off the leading "---":

```
blocks = File.foreach('test.txt').slice_before(/^---/).map { |ary|
  ary.shift if ary.first[/^---/]
  ary.map(&:chomp)
}
```

After running that `blocks` is:

```
[
  ["requestID: saldksadk", "time: 92389389", "action: foobarr"],
  ["requestID: 2393029", "time: 92389389", "action: helloworld", "source: email"],
  ["requestID: skjflkjasf3", "time: 92389389", "userAgent: mobile browser"],
  ["requestID: gdfgfdsdf", "time: 92389389", "action: randoms"]
]
```

A bit more tweaking:

```
blocks = File.foreach('test.txt').slice_before(/^---/).map { |ary|
  ary.shift if ary.first[/^---/]
  Hash[ary.map{ |s| s.chomp.split(':') }]
}
```

and `blocks` will be:

```
[
  {"requestID"=>" saldksadk", "time"=>" 92389389", "action"=>" foobarr"},
  {"requestID"=>" 2393029", "time"=>" 92389389", "action"=>" helloworld", "source"=>" email"},
  {"requestID"=>" skjflkjasf3", "time"=>" 92389389", "userAgent"=>" mobile browser"},
  {"requestID"=>" gdfgfdsdf", "time"=>" 92389389", "action"=>" randoms"}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can read through the file line-by-line. For each line, we'll check if it's a record separator or a key: value pair. If the former, we'll add the current record to the record list. If the latter, we'll add the k:v pair to the current record.

```
records = []
record = {}
open("data.txt", "r").each do |line|
  if line.start_with? "-"
    records << record unless record.empty?
    record = {}
  else
    k, v = line.split(":", 2).map(&:strip)
    record[k] = v
  end
end
records << record unless record.empty?
```

This produces something like:

```
[{"requestID"=>"saldksadk", "time"=>"92389389", "action"=>"foobarr"},
 {"requestID"=>"2393029", "time"=>"92389389", "action"=>"helloworld", "source"=>"email"},
 {"requestID"=>"skjflkjasf3", "time"=>"92389389", "userAgent"=>"mobile browser"}, 
 {"requestID"=>"gdfgfdsdf", "time"=>"92389389", "action"=>"randoms"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Very basic way to do it, that keeps it simple and efficient:

```
blocks = []
current_block = {}

sep_range = 0..3
sep_value = "----"

split_pattern = /:\s*/

File.open("filename.txt", 'r') do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    if line[sep_range] == sep_value
      blocks << current_block unless current_block.empty?
      current_block = {}
    else
      key, value = line.split(split_pattern, 2)
      current_block[key] = value
    end
  end
end

blocks << current_block unless current_block.empty?
```

Something key to point out is that we are avoiding creating unnecessary duplicate objects inside the loop (the range, test string, and split regex pattern), and instead defining them before the loop begins, this saves a little bit of time and memory. On a file of 500mb, this could be significant.